# How can I extract content from web source code with re.findall?

Tags: python, python-3.x

i have extracted a long web source code and within the long source code   what i want to extract is the content within the span tag.

```
<span class="a-size-medium a-color-base a-text-normal">
  Apple iPhone 6S, GSM Unlocked, 16GB - Rose Gold (Renewed)
</span>
```

i.e. i want to retrieve 'Apple iPhone 6S, GSM Unlocked, 16GB - Rose Gold (Renewed)'

How can I use re.findall to extract the relevant contact within the tags? or any other easier way to do so? thanks.

Comment: You should generally avoid [parsing HTML with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1678362), consider using an existing HTML parser. In particular, beautifulsoup makes extracting values from HTML very easy

Comment: You can use code blocks (the `{}` button in the editor) to correctly represent HTML in your question, you should check the edit history of your question as others tried to fix that and you might just want to rollback to a previous version.

Comment: I have tried BeautifulSoup4 and HtmlParser.  I actually like BS4 the best for HTML Parsing.  Its been awhile, but it may not be native on your machine and it may need to be fetched with PIP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use BeautifulSoup or something similar for this kind of task. Once you have your page's html in a variable, such as `html` in my example below, it is easy to find elements. Use the `.text` property to extract what you are looking for.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = # I used your source code provided
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
items = soup.find_all('span', {'class': 'a-size-medium'})

for item in items:
    print(item.text)
# Apple iPhone 6S, GSM Unlocked, 16GB - Rose Gold (Renewed)
```

Of course, this will work in the example code you provided, but I suspect you might have to play around with isolating the part you want to parse.

Answer (score 1):

As `Brian Cohan` answered - it's not best practice to use regex in order to parse HTML source code. I would recommend to use [BS4](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#) or [html.parser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.parser.html). But still, answering your question, you can use this regex: `(?:(?<=<span)(.*)(?<=>)).*(?=</span>)` in order to obtain the data.

Answer (score 0):

https://scrapy.org/ is a good library to do what you want and you have plenty utility to get tags/ pattern of your HTML web page